# Is there ever any advantage to using an unconditional MIPS branch rather than a jump?

Tags: assembly, mips

I am learning MIPS assembly at college currently, and am struggling to get a feel for the language. As I understand it, the jump command allows me to jump further in memory than a branch command would given the extra bits available. Why then would I ever use an unconditional branch rather than using a jump?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MIPS doesn't have an unconditional branch. It is probably a pseudo instruction provided by your assembler, like BEQ R1,R1.  Branches are desirable because they allow code to be located anywhere in memory without requiring [*relocation*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relocation_%28computing%29).  Desirable on machine without a MMU and to implement shared libraries.  Backgrounder for that is in this [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code).

Comment: Thanks, precisely the kind of answer I was hoping for. :)

Answer (score 4):

The jump has more immediate bits, and is an absolute address.  A branch uses an offset.  One is position independent for example the other isnt.

Comment: Thanks, I understand this much. I was trying to understand why I would send a b Label instruction rather than j Label one.

Comment: much of the time there is no difference, but one has more of a reach than the other and one is relative and the other is not.  unconditional branch in mips is a pseudo instruction BTW, look at the encoding