# MIPS branch instead of jump

Tags: assembly, mips32

What is the reason for using a branch with a predetermined condition, such as this:

```
beq $0, $0, TEST
```

Instead of just using a jump like this?

```
j TEST
```

Branches are used to test for conditions, but in this case, the branch has been used with a condition that will always be true. So why use it over a jump? Is it somehow faster?

I came across this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14764133/is-there-ever-any-advantage-to-using-an-unconditional-mips-branch-rather-than-a), but I don't know if it is indeed the correct answer to my question because I don't know anything about relocation yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `J` instruction is encoded as follows:

```
----------------------------
| opcode |   instr_index   |
----------------------------
```

`instr_index` is the least significant 28 bits of the target address, shifted right by 2 to give you a 26-bit value. And the address you'll end up jumping to is `(PC & 0xF0000000) | (instr_index << 2)`

The `BEQ` variant is encoded as follows:

```
-----------------------------
| opcode | 0 | 0 |  offset  |
-----------------------------
```

And the address you'll end up branching to is `PC + sign_extend(offset << 2)`.

(Note, in both cases `PC` is the address of the instruction immediately after the branch/jump instruction, not the branch/jump instruction itself).

Now, let's say that you have the following code:

```
main:
j foo
nop
foo:
```

And that this code is originally intended to be loaded at address `0x00400024`. The address of `foo` will then be `0x0040002c`, and the `J` instruction will be encoded as `(2 << 26) | (0x0040002c >> 2)` = `0x0810000b`.

But then you decide that you want to relocate this code (copy it to some other location in memory and execute it at that location). Let's say that your code is now executing at `0x00410000`. In this case we would want the `J` instruction to jump to `0x00410008`, but it will still be jumping to `0x0040002c` (`(0x00410004 & 0xF0000000) | (0x010000b << 2)` = `0x0040002c`).

If on the other hand you had used `BEQ` you would have the instruction word `0x10000001` (`(4 << 26) | (4 >> 2)`). Even if the code is relocated you will still end up branching to the correct address: `0x00410004 + (1 << 2)` = `0x00410008`.